# Google html To google drive spreadsheet(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

Is it possible that the outcome of an html (form) is generated to an google drive spreadsheet ?

[Like This ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537569/using-just-javascript-to-submit-information-to-google-drive-spreadsheet) (not working)

Comment: Sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) or [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) to achieve this.

### Apps Script

> Google Apps Script is a scripting language based on JavaScript that lets you do new and cool things with Google Apps like Docs, Sheets, and Forms. There's nothing to install — we give you a code editor right in your browser, and your scripts run on Google's servers.

It is easy to use you just need an HTML file, JS file and Apps Script code that will process your data to your Google Sheet.

Here is the code from [Step by step setup to send form data to Google Sheets](http://railsrescue.com/blog/2015-05-28-step-by-step-setup-to-send-form-data-to-google-sheets/).

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Contact Form - sent to a Google Sheet -->
    <form id='foo'>
      <p>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input id='name' name='name' type='text'>
      </p><p>
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input id='email' name='email' type='email'>
      </p><p>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input id='phone' name='phone' type='tel'>
      </p><p>
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea id='message' name='message' rows='5'></textarea>
      </p>
        <div id='success'></div>
        <button type='submit'>Send</button>
    </form>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src='google-sheet.js'></script>
</html>
```

JS

```
// Variable to hold request
var request;

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#foo").submit(function(event){

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "SCRIPT URL GOES HERE",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        console.log(response);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

GS

```
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [];
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Here are links you can visit to familiarize yourself with Apps Scrip, its functions and code implementation (also check the link above for the official documents of Google).

- [Tutorial 1](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/)
- [Tutorial 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/)

### NOTE:

> You have to publish your apps script code to get the web app URL.

I haven't tried it but I think you can  use Sheets API. Using `HTTP` Request and OAuth if your file is not public or access user data to pass the outcome to Google Sheets.

Hope this helps.